# weblogic.Admin: command not found

Tags: weblogic, weblogic12c, weblogic-10.x, weblogic11g

I am using linux terminal with below code to get server status but i am getting weblogic.Admin: command not found, any lead would be appreciable.

```
cd /opt/SP/WEB_DATA/weblogic/wls12130/user_projects/domains/pega/bin
. ./setDomainEnv.sh
export CLASSPATH=/WEB_DATA/weblogic/wls12130/wlserver/server/lib/weblogic.jar

ServerState=/opt/SP/WEB_DATA/mw/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java weblogic.Admin -url http://t3://localhost:7001 -username weblogic -password weblogic1
GET -pretty -type ServerRuntime -property State |grep -i State|awk '{print $2}'| rev | cut -c 1- | rev
```

Comment: java is not found or weblogic.Admin or the GET command ?

Answer (score 1):

weblogic.Admin has been deprecated for a while now. Use wlst instead.

```
(location of ORACLE_HOME)/wlserver/common/bin/wlst.sh
wls:/offline>connect('weblogic','weblogic1','t3://localhost:7001')
wls:/DOMAIN/serverConfig>state('WLAdmin','Server')
```

*WLAdmin is the name of the admin server*

You can place the above commands in a python script and execute it using wlst